# Mysql remove binary log

Tags: mysql-5.5

Hello everyone we got situation over here.
So, our mysql server is running out disk, after some investigation 
we found out that our mysql binary file have eat too many space.
In order to purge the binary we have to log in to mysql, but mysql cannot be 
started. So what should we do ?

Comment: Temporarily add some disk space?

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way is to add little more storage, start, and then issue `purge binary logs to name_of_binlog_XXX;`. If you can temporarily move some files off of the volume that will work, too. Or, with little risk, move an unused MyISAM files (frm, MYD, MYI, etc) from unused DB, start, purge, and copy it back.

If this is not an option, you're looking at manually removing one of old binlog files to start it up. I would then make sure the *mysql_binlog*.index file is cleaned up as well.